# Strong name export from a key container

Tags: .net, export, code-signing, strongname, rsacryptoserviceprovider

We do have a build server, which contains our private key, used to sign the delay-signed assemblies, in a key container. We are now creating another build server and no one seems to know, where the original key file is, so we're trying to export the key from the original server and import into the new one.

To do the export, we are using this:

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider key;
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.KeyContainerName = "nameOfOurContainer";
cp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
var blob = key.ExportCspBlob(true);
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath,  FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    fs.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
}
```

to import - this

```
CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
cp.KeyContainerName = containerName;
cp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
cp.KeyNumber = (int)KeyNumber.Signature;

RSACryptoServiceProvider key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);

using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var blob = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(blob,0,(int)fs.Length);
    key.ImportCspBlob(blob);
    key.PersistKeyInCsp = true;             
}
```

The keys are being exported and imported successfully, but the signing on the new server is not working - we're getting

```
Key pair does not match public key from assembly
```

So, I suspect, that either our import, or export process is wrong. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can export key containers with the below command line:

```
aspnet_regiis -px "SameplKeys" keys.xml -pri
```

This exports the key container `SampleKeys` to the `keys.xml` file. The `-pri` option includes private key information.

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues with RSACryptoServiceProvider is that it will generate a keypair if none exists. It makes it harder to know if you're reading an existing key (or using something entirely new).

I don't recall exactly how the strongnames key were stored (it's been a while) wrt CryptoAPI. However I don't believe them to be in the machine store (not by default anyway) so

```
cp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
```

should not be used (in the export, nor the import).

I don't recall the key slot (e.g. KeyNumber.Signature) but it should be identical in both your export and import code (try both :-).

If that does not work try to detect if the export or the import is the issue. Use the **sn** options to see if the exported public key (**-tp**) match the one used on the assemblies (**-Tp**).

You can also have a look at Mono [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/sn.cs) for its **sn** tool. It does support the options but I don't recall if they were fully compatible with MS version (wrt key containers) and things might have changes a bit since FX 1.x ;-)

Comment: Well, tried playing arround with the flags property for the export - it was generating different keys for each setting. Consistent, but different. And none of them was the right one. Will continue investigation tommorow.